# Angular modal not updates with component variable change

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using a component for sending SMS and it is added to the nagigation bar component like this :

```
<ng-template #smsModal let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <div class="modal">
        <app-sms></app-sms>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

The sms component HTML looks likes the following :

```
    <form>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="send.mobileNumber" #ctrl="ngModel" name="mobileNumber">

       <button class="send-SMS-btn ripple" (click)="sendMessage()" [disabled]="textSending">
          <span *ngIf="!textSending">Send Message</span>
          <app-spinner *ngIf="textSending"></app-spinner>
      </button>
      <div class="textmsg text-danger" *ngIf="textError">{{textError}}</div>
      <div class="textmsg success" *ngIf="textSuccess">{{textSuccess}}</div>
</form>
```

the method `sendMessage()` has the following code :

```
 this.textSending    = false;

 if (_.isEmpty(this.send.mobileNumber)) {
            this.textError = "Please enter a valid phone number";
            return false;
        }

        this.textSending    = true;
        this.textSuccess    = null;

        // API call and stuff
}
```

When I console the `this.textError`, it is giving the correct error message, but this is not updated in view. The error container `div` itself is not populated and also the `spinner` is not showing. Somehow, the view is not detecting changes . The API call is triggered, but it also not showing error message, even if it is showing in console. How this can be fixed ?

Comment: Can you add a plunker to it (if possible)? So people can resolve it update you.

Answer (score 3):

Probably need to restart the digest cycle again. use the `changeDetectorRef` service

```
constructor( 
    private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
) {
}
```

call the `detectChanges` method inside `sendMessage` method

```
   if (_.isEmpty(this.send.mobileNumber)) {
            this.textError = "Please enter a valid phone number";
            return false;
   }

   this.textSending    = true;
   this.textSuccess    = null;

   this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); // start the cycle again
```

Comment: This is working fine. But is there any other better way to invoke the change without explicitly calling `detetctChanges()`

Comment: try this without using the underscore js

Answer (score 1):

A typical way for me to address input data from passed into a component is to declare the input as a BehaviorSubject.

For example:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component-selector',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html'
})
export class MyComponent {

  @Input()
  public set yourErrorTextMessage(data) {
    this.yourErrorTextMessageSubject.next(data);
  };

  private yourErrorTextMessageSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");

}
```

What this does is tie the actual value to the behavior subject, and the template gets notified of any changes to it, including values prior to the template initializing. Thus your error message can be updated asynchronously and your component will get the value for the last error message whether it happened before or after the initialization.

Comment: So here in which component I need to make this change ? The main component or the included one ?